# PDO duplicate values in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I need to get some currency ids from db, this is my code

```
$arr = [];

$currency_codes = array("USD", "RUB");
$currency_codes_in = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($currency_codes), '?'));
$query = "SELECT `curr_id` FROM `dictionary_currency` WHERE `curr_code` IN (". $currency_codes_in .")";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
foreach ($currency_codes as $k => $id) {
    $stmt->bindValue(($k+1), $id);
}

$stmt->execute();
$currencies = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($currencies as $currency)
{
    foreach($currency as $key => $value)
    {
        $arr[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($arr);
exit();
```

this is `$currencies` array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [curr_id] => 643
            [0] => 643
            [curr_code] => RUB
            [1] => RUB
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [curr_id] => 840
            [0] => 840
            [curr_code] => USD
            [1] => USD
        )

)
```

and this is `$arr`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 643
    [1] => 643
    [2] => 840
    [3] => 840
)
```

I don't understand why I get duplicate values in arrays and how to prevent it?

Comment: Which key you want from `$currencies` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is problematic:

```
foreach($currencies as $currency) {
     foreach($currency as $key => $value) {
           $arr[] = $value;
     }
}
```

Just use a simple

```
foreach($currencies as $currency) {
    $arr[] = $currency[0];
}
```

***Edit #1:***

Using your `$currencies` and old query, I got the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [curr_id] => 643
        [0] => 643
        [curr_code] => RUB
        [1] => RUB
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [curr_id] => 840
        [0] => 840
        [curr_code] => USD
        [1] => USD
    )
)

Array
(
    [0] => 643
    [1] => 643
    [2] => RUB
    [3] => RUB
    [4] => 840
    [5] => 840
    [6] => USD
    [7] => USD
)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! but I still don't understand why I get duplicate values in arrays (

Comment: are you sure with your dump? using your old query, `$arr` should have the values USD and RUB as well.. checkout my dump using your `$currencies` data.. @Heidel

Answer (score 2):

PDO is a database wrapper that can do many things for you. For example,

- bind input values right in execute()
- [get you returned data already in the desired format](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#column)

So in fact you need two times less code than you have now:

```
$currency_codes = array("USD", "RUB");
$currency_codes_in = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($currency_codes), '?'));
$query = "SELECT `curr_id` FROM `dictionary_currency` WHERE `curr_code` IN ($currency_codes_in)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
$stmt->execute($currency_codes);
$arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

or I would rather propose to make it like

```
$query = "SELECT curr_code, curr_id FROM dictionary_currency WHERE `curr_code` IN ($currency_codes_in)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
$stmt->execute($currency_codes);
$arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is getting old. But here is the solution to prevent the duplicate values from PDO. 
Just using this:

```
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Instead of this:

```
$stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score -1):

use following query 
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT `curr_id` FROM `dictionary_currency` WHERE `curr_code` IN (". $currency_codes_in .")";